# Is there an option to destroy all child records at once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have three models

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :b, dependent: :destroy
end

class B < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :a
    has_many :c, dependent: :delete_all
end

class C < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :b
end
```

When I delete instance of class A, all of the dependent records are being destroyed one by one. Is there an option to destroy them at once?

Comment: Delete_all will do that however it won't trigger their corresponding destroy callbacks if they have any. Update_all and delete_all bypass ActiveRecord so they're much faster however this speed is gained at the cost of not instantiating every instance.

Comment: That's the thing. I know that there are 'delete_all', but i want to destroy all B's instances in one transaction and C's in other (or both at the same time if possible)

Comment: You can wrap it in one transaction  but you can't run it in one statement to the database since it has to instantiate each object and run the objects callbacks (in this case destroy).

Comment: I suggest using foreign keys with an `on_delete` setting for this. IMO stuff like this belongs in the database itself, not in the models.